# Symfony2 Form label collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony, label

I am triing to elaborate a form where users can give a MARK (positive or negative one, +1 or -1) to some ANSWER which are linked to a QUESTION.

Exemple:
Click on the right answer

```
Which city would you like to live in? 
Paris (+1) (-1)
Berlin (+1) (-1)
London (+1) (-1)
```

So I have 3 objects: QUESTION<-(OneToMany)->ANSWER<-(OneToMany)->MARK

the Only task a user can do in this form is set up +1 or -1 (A MARK) associeted to a ANSWER which is associated to a QUESTION.
The form is for one QUESTION and all the ANSWER related to this QUESTION

I am lost... how can I do that with Symfony2?
Do I have to do a collection of ANSWERS? but I do not want to edit the ANSWERS... only edit the MARKS of the ANSWERS. (actually ANSWER is more like the Label here)

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need two objects here:

```
QUESTION<-(OneToMany)->ANSWER
```

Each `ANSWER` will have a field `MARK` that can be either +1 or -1. You need collection of `ANSWER` objects linked to a `QUESTION` object. Pretty simple.

Comment: thks but actually each user can give a different mark. so I do have a score field which is the sum up of all marks from different users. So mark is not only a field, it is really an entity by itself.